# Why is my jupyter notebook python dash framework not displaying anything?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, frameworks, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am facing an issue while working on a school project that involves building a front-end dashboard using the Dash framework. The project required me to fill out the FIXME sections of a preset code and use the CRUD functions of a database that I had worked on before. Although I have completed the dashboard file, it does not display anything when I run it. According to my professor, our MongoDB database with a large number of selections may take a few minutes to load. However, I have run the code for over 30 minutes while playing video games and still cannot get it to work.

Attempt #1:
Things that I have tried is attempt to uninstall the dash framework and reinstall it. Being that I am on the schools virtual machine, this does not work as I do not have access to do so.

Attempt #2:
I reviewed my code and saw that I have repeated a function, so I was wondering if this caused a loop issue where it cant compile correctly, so I deleted the duplicate function. This still ran with a blank page.

Attempt #3:
I added a Unique HTML Header  'html.H1("AnimalShelter - Adam Resemius")' but this does not display on the page either.

### Attempt #4:
Change the ".py" file for AnimalShelter to a ".IPYNB" this makes the filetype the same as the Dash File. The result was the file module cannot be found.

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
13 from pymongo import MongoClient
14
---> 15 from AnimalShelter import AnimalShelter
16
17

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AnimalShelter'

#Attempt 5:
Run without the mongo server to see if it is connected. This errored out so I knew it was connecting and using the database.

#Attempt 6: Run a parametrized query so it only pulls a select few documents instead of the whole thing. Still displayed nothing in the output.

Here is my code:

```
AnimalShelter.py
====================================================================
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


# Creating class AnimalShelter

class AnimalShelter(object):
    # Enter CRUD operations here
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        try:
            self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:38761/AAC' % (username, password))
            self.database = self.client['AAC']
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Unable to connect to database: {}".format(str(e)))

    # Implementing create functionality
    def create(self, data):
        try:
            if data is not None:
                self.database.animals.insert_one(data)
                return True
            else:
                raise ValueError("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Unable to save data: {}".format(str(e)))

    # Implementing read functionality
    def read(self, data):
        try:
            if data is not None:
                result = self.database.animals.find(search, {"_id":False})
                return list(result)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Nothing to read, because data parameter is empty")
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Unable to read data: {}".format(str(e)))

    # Implementing update functionality
    def update(self, query, data):
        try:
            if query is not None and data is not None:
                result = self.database.animals.update_one(query, {"$set": data})
                return result
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unable to update data, because data query or data parameter is empty.")
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Unable to update data: {}".format(str(e)))

    # Implementing delete functionality
    def delete(self, query):
        try:
            if query is not None:
                count = self.database.animals.count_documents(query)
                if count > 0:
                    self.database.animals.delete_one(query)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False, "No documents found to be deleted"
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unable to delete data, because query parameter is empty")
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Unable to delete data: {}".format(str(e)))








Dash.ipynb
=====================================================================
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash
import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pymongo import MongoClient

from AnimalShelter import AnimalShelter


###########################
# Data Manipulation / Model
###########################

username = "aacuser"
password = "Password1"
shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)


# class read method must support return of cursor object and accept projection json input
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({'name': 'Lucy'}))





#########################
# Dashboard Layout / View
#########################
app = JupyterDash('SimpleExample')


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='hidden-div', style={'display':'none'}),
    html.Center(html.B(html.H1('SNHU CS-340 Dashboard'))),
    html.Hr(),
    html.H1("AnimalShelter - Adam Resemius"),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-id',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),

        # Creating filter functionality:
        filter_action='custom',
        # Since there is a lot of data values, I am chosing to use a scrollwheel with pagination 
        page_size=100, #using initial size of 100 to see how it looks
        style_table={"height": "300px", "overflowY": "auto"},

        # Adding striped rows for visuals for the rows 
        style_data_conditional=[
                {
                    'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
                    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(248, 248, 248)'
                }
            ],
            style_header={
                'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
                'fontWeight': 'bold'
            },
            style_cell={
                'textAlign': 'left',
                'minWidth': '0px', 'maxWidth': '180px',
                'whiteSpace': 'normal'
            }
        # Adding Filters

    ),
    html.Br(),
     html.Hr(),
     html.Div(
            id='map-id',
            className='col s12 m6',
            )
])

#############################################
# Interaction Between Components / Controller
#############################################
#This callback will highlight a row on the data table when the user selects it
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-id', 'style_data_conditional'),
    [Input('datatable-id', 'selected_columns')]
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]
# Callback for the filter function
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-id', 'derived_viewport_data'),
    Input('datatable-id', 'viewport_data'),
    Input('datatable-id', 'sort_by'),
    Input('datatable-id', 'filter_query'))  # add filter_query
def update_table(viewport_data, sort_by, filter_query):
    # convert filter query to filter dictionary
    if filter_query:
        filtering_expressions = filter_query.split(' && ')
        d = {}
        for filter_part in filtering_expressions:
            col_name, operator, filter_value = \
                filter_part.split(' ')
            if operator in ('eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'):
                # these operators match pandas series operator method names
                d[col_name] = getattr(pd.Series, operator)(filter_value)
            elif operator == 'contains':
                d[col_name] = filter_value
        filter_dict = d

        # apply filters to data
        if filter_query:
            data = df.query(' & '.join(f"{k} == '{v}'" for k, v in filter_dict.items()))
        else:
            data = df

        # apply sorting to data
        if len(sort_by):
            data = data.sort_values(
                [col['column_id'] for col in sort_by],
                ascending=[
                    col['direction'] == 'asc'
                    for col in sort_by
                ],
                inplace=False
            )

        # return viewport data
        return data.iloc[
            viewport_data['row_start']:viewport_data['row_end'],
            viewport_data['column_start']:viewport_data['column_end']
        ].to_dict('records')
    
#FIXME Add in the code for your geolocation chart
@app.callback(
    Output('map-id', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-id', "derived_viewport_data")]
)
def update_map(viewData):
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(viewData)
    
    markers = []
    for i in range(len(dff)):
        animal = dff.iloc[i]
        marker = dl.Marker(
            position=[animal["location_lat"], animal["location_long"]],
            children=[
                dl.Tooltip(animal["breed"]),
                dl.Popup([
                    html.H1("Animal Name"),
                    html.P(animal["animal_id"])
                ])
            ]
        )
        markers.append(marker)

    return dl.Map(
        style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'}, 
        center=[dff["location_lat"].mean(), dff["location_long"].mean()], 
        zoom=10, 
        children=[
            dl.TileLayer(),
            *markers
        ]
    )
shelter.read({})




app
```

Comment: Hello, Just letting you know that I figured this out. Due to me using Jupyter Notebooks and the dash library, the filter function was already included within the framework, I needed to delete the one that I made separately and use their options. you can do so with adding  "filter_action='native'" to the code.